# dns forwarding for specific zone not working - bind

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dns, centos-6, bind

In bind we created specific zone and got set a forward options, but it fails to resolve.
Details as follow,

For mydomain.com dns working fine.
but we use developer site called mydomain.com.dev
we have forwarded for dev. but still not working.
It works well with windows dns.

we tried with two forward scenarios as below, still no luck.
we have also tried on centos and ubuntu.

scenario 1 :

```
zone "dev" {
    type forward;
    forwarders { x.x.x.x;};

};
```

scenario 2:

```
zone "mydomain.com.dev" {
    type forward;
    forwarders { x.x.x.x;};

};
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably do not have recursion enabled for the view these zone definitions are in.  Recursion is required for forwarding to work properly.

You might also try with a stub zone.  Stub zones are less brittle over time but assume correctly setup and advertised authoritative DNS servers to learn the current set (not always the case, unfortunately).